# Building deployable JavaScript with Grunt

Tags: php, build, content-management-system, gruntjs, minify

I'd like to know how other people are automating their JavaScript build process in CMS website builds.

I currently use Grunt to automate SASS->CSS minification which works really well because your not overwriting your sass files with compressed code.

You can't really do the same thing with JavaScript though because you would be overwriting your JS if you compressed it.

Obviously you could build .min.js files instead, but then you have to manually update file names in your html templates.

I've also seen and done builds were you have a www folder and then a build folder; the build folder getting all the minified assets. This is nice, but tends to only work for smaller static sites in my experience.

One idea we've played around with is having an unminified-js folder for production JS, then grunt builds into a script folder which is referenced from your templates.

Any insight into a neat process would be gratefully received.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's the [`connect`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) task, where you can serve [more than one location](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#base) for a single path. When the page looks for a file, it looks for it in the first folder in the array. If not there, it goes to the next one in the list and so on - but the path still points to the first location.

Comment: While I like Yeoman, seems like this answer is not what he's asking (how to do this with Grunt).

Comment: @jakerella I was actually stating Yeoman to tell you that it had a neat Grunt task which should be of help.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with Yeoman and connect, but it isn't really that suitable for the scenario I outlined, for instance the web app generator is good for handmade apps and non content managed stuff. Not really what I'm looking for when working with an existing CMS (php based in this case but sometimes .Net).

Comment: @stikoo Then you should tag PHP and .NET

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am unclear on what you are asking, but why don't you just have your minified files outputted elsewhere that you will use for production, and the original JS files in a separate folder that you can edit and then run grunt and have them outputted elsewhere. Here is an example grunt file that I used on a recent project.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
concat: {
  appJs: {
    src: [
    './templates/*.js',
    './js/*.js'
    ],
    dest: '../js/featuredProduct.<%= pkg.version %>.js'
  }

},
handlebars: {
  all: {
    src: 'templates/*.hbs',
    dest: './templates/templates.js'
  },
  options: {
    namespace: 'Handlebars.templates'
  }
},
uglify: {
  options: {
    mangle: false
  },
  build: {
    files: {
      '../js/featuredProduct.<%= pkg.version %>.min.js' : ['../js/featuredProduct.<%= pkg.version %>.js']
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  handlebars: {
    files: './templates/*.hbs',
    tasks: ['handlebars', 'concat']
  },
  concat: {
    files: ['./js/**/*.js'],
    tasks: 'concat'
  },
  uglify: {
    files: ['../js/featuredProduct.<%= pkg.version %>.js'],
    tasks: 'uglify'
  }
}
});


//This task is a multi task, meaning that grunt will automatically iterate over all less targets if a target is not specified.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-handlebars');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

// Default task.
grunt.registerTask('default', ['handlebars','concat','uglify']);
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I have a very similar setup at the moment, just without the concat stage, as I'm using require.js for module loading. Do you just always have a reference to the concat/uglified version in your templates? This is what I was getting at when I mentioned the manual step of having to change the script.js reference to script.min.js within templates on deployment. I don't want to debug uglyified JS in production you see.

Comment: You're also adding a pkg.version to your files so do you have a manual step of changing the script src from within your html?

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense now. I work in an environment called web control, there is a call to my JS which is saved in an element. So whenever I update the file using grunt I need to copy and paste the new code into the element, which is called throughout the site. So I think our situations are slightly different. I edit the unminified version locally, run the grunt tasks, copy the code into the element, and push the element to production.